# Magento 2 - Can't go to Category page from admin panel

Tags: magento2, category

so I have a few problems that I want to solve but I can't and I tried everything!

> 1. I don't have any root category and I can't create via PHP file don't know why
> 2. I can't go to admin>products>categories, it gives me a to many redirects error

Yesterday I had a Root Category...

So I'm scared because I probably deleted the category from the database and now I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: You have to enable magento log and check what happen

Comment: Is it a clean install of magento 2 ?

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma yes

Comment: @AmitBera how do I enable that ?

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma i added a print

Comment: @AmitBera I added a print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have deleted the root category i can suggest you a solution. The solution is that create another category at the parent level and then go to `Stores > Settings > All Stores` select your store from the grid and the form will open , in that select your new category as the root category. If you had sub categories assigned in the root category, drag those categories into this new root category.

From your question what i can assume is that you are saying that root category was deleted automatically, for that you will have to debug the reason because again there are chances that this new root category also can get deleted.

Comment: How do I create another category at parent level ?

Comment: Yes, because you have already lost the existing root category.

Comment: I´m asking how do I do that if i can´t go to the categories page

Comment: Have you deleted anything from the code or installed some third party module ?

Comment: If you haven't installed any third party module and have not deleted anything from core code of magento 2, then i will just you to run the below commands:
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I could do that but i don´t have access to CLI it´s a shared host

Comment: I think your shared host should be providing access to CLI from ssh access.

Comment: If you do not have access to CLI at presnt, can you flush Magento 2 cache from Magento 2 admin panel and check the category page.

Comment: Nope they don´t

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it !

So I had a database backup !

And I compared some tables and I probably made the mistake to delete some data.

Thanks for your time you all !